# Automaticly Click a button on a remote website Every 50 Minutes?

Tags: java, server, remote-access, minecraft, host

I got a mine craft server online (https://server.pro/control-panel/1446793/) and I need to click the restart button every 45-55 Minutes. How can I do this? Is it possible to Do using GC (google code)? If not do i use java? Is it even possible? I have no idea what to do. Any response is helpful (even if it says something I have done wrong :) )

If i do need to use JAVA what program would i use to make the script (If there is one)

Comment: Honestly I think you're better off using something like `curl` to hit the endpoint with some locally-saved credentials. Similar to: https://www.drupal.org/node/1795770

Comment: How would I go about that

Comment: This is too-broad, you are asking about 5 questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with either of those languages, however I have made an autoclicker in C. It can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/autoclickcpp/). If you are unwilling to use mine, there are many other autoclickers out there.

Comment: BTW I would love to help with your server. I bought Minecraft back when it cost $5, and have set and hosted multiple servers.

Comment: Sure if you want to talk email me at skydazz2000@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. You could write some javascript that is injected into the page by plugin. You could also do it in Java with a [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) although that would be more hacky than the first solution. Also the [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) library may help you as it's used for writing tests that will click different things on the web page.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to click the button from the remote to restart the server.

You can do that with a plugin, for example [auto-restart plugin](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/autorestart.2538/)